# Achievements button broken on topbar

Tags: bug, status-completed, achievements-dialog

Since yesterday evening it seems that the achievements button is broken for me.

Clicking it just gives me an empty box (with a perpetual loading indicator):

[image: Emptiness]

and looking in Chrome's devtools it appears that the call to get content is returning a 500:

[image: Devtools output]

The number in the indicator still appears to be working correctly but I'm essentially unable to clear it because I can't successfully view what those reputation changes *are*.

What I've tried so far:

- Visited different sites across the network - problem follows me.
- Used a different device - I initially encountered this on my phone last night but the problem has persisted to using my desktop PC at work today.

Replicated on:

- Microsoft Edge (101.0.1210.53) on Android 11 (Build 2022.110.15 on Surface Duo2)
- Microsoft Edge (101.0.1210.53) on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0.19044, Build 19044)
- Google Chrome (101.0.4951.67) on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0.19044, Build 19044)

Above screenshots are from Chrome - but there's no visual difference in Edge and the Edge Devtools report the same HTTP 500 response from the topbar/achievements URL. The actual content of the response is the standard *Oops! Something Bad Happened* friendly error page.

Comment: No repro on Chrome on Android and FireFox on MacOS

Comment: No repro using Firefox on Win 10. (This did happen for me during the brief SE downtimes yesterday, but not outside it.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should be fixed now. Long story short, we had some literal miscommunication between the Teams infrastructure and the public Q&A SQL servers. Lessons were learned, firewall rules nudged, and the bits should be once again flowing freely.

Thanks for the report! Please let us know if you are still seeing any issues.

Comment: All good now! Appreciate the quick response